# Basic C formatting issue

Tags: c, format

For this assignment I want my program to output the requested output.  My issue lies in the formatting.
Link to the problem in question:
[image: http://i1306.photobucket.com/albums/s576/sammyr2011/eng32111_zps3a5d52fd.png]

The output of the program:
[image: http://i1306.photobucket.com/albums/s576/sammyr2011/outputofquestion1_zps2aa9558a.png]

For whatever reason my x value is not increasing by a factor of ten and as far as the spacing is concerned I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//declare global variables
    int x = 1;
    double num = .1234;

//prototype functions
partA(double num);

int main() {
    double a;
    a = partA(num);
    printf("%lf\n",a);
}

/*First Function, x and num increase by a factor
of ten. */ 
partA(double num) {
    for(x; x <= 10000; x *= 10) {
        for (num; num <= 1234; num *= 10) {
            printf("%d%4lf\n",x, num);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

Comment: A subtle, but interesting problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After accepted answer.  This one uses fields widths and not spaces as required by the post.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void partAB(const char *format, double num) {
  double d = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
     printf(format, d, num);
     d *= 10;
     num *= 10;
   }
   printf("\n");
}

void partA(double num) {
  partAB("%5.0lf  %.4lf\n", num);
  }

void partB(double num) {
  partAB("%5.0lf  %9.3le\n", num);
  }

int main() {
  double x = 0.1234;
  partA(x);
  partB(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spacing is because only outer loop is executing which contains printf

Answer (score 1):

It is not increasing because you have a For inside another For, you have to increment X inside the For of "num"

Something like:

```
int x = 1;
for (num; num <= 1234; num *= 10)
{
    printf("%5d%3s%4lf\n",x, " ", num);
    x*=10;
}
```

Cheers

Edit: before I forgot the spaces, it should be fine now

Comment: You must use field widths and not spaces or tabs.

Comment: lol... down vote because I missed something? Aren't you human?

Comment: @tweellt: DW was because answer was accepted and incorrect.

Comment: Ok PxL, it had a mistake but that's why we use comments to ask or alert others. But that's ok... don't worry about it. Cheers

Comment: If this works, its lucky.  `double num = .1234;` then `num *= 10` 4 times might just end up with `num == 1234.000...0001` and fail the `num <= 1234` test.

Comment: When I did this, I admit, I wrote it here directly without testing, but I have test it now and it does work.

Comment: @tweellt The subtle issues is that the terminating condition `num <= 1234` is ever so sensitive to the start condition of 0.1234 and its multiplication by 10 4 times.  Typical floating point cannot represent 0.1234 exactly and each x10 will then get a further rounded result.  When x is _near_ 1234.0, and the terminating condition is `num <= 1234`, `x` may be just above (on another machine) and terminate after only 4 loops.  Using `x <= 10000` is certainly safer, but it too has troubles at higher powers.

Answer (score 1):

this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ee(int e){
  int i, ret;
  ret=1;
  for(i=0;i<e;i++)
    ret *= 10;
  return ret;
}

int main(void) {
  int i;
  printf("a)\n");
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%5d %.4f\n",ee(i), 0.1234 * ee(i));
  printf("\nb)\n");
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%5d %.3e\n",ee(i), 0.1234 * ee(i));
}
```

gives:

```
a)
    1 0.1234
   10 1.2340
  100 12.3400
 1000 123.4000
10000 1234.0000

b)
    1 1.234e-01
   10 1.234e+00
  100 1.234e+01
 1000 1.234e+02
10000 1.234e+03
```

Comment: thx :), there are a lots of better and faster ways, but i think this code is easy to read and understand and meets the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Without if, switch and spaces and tabs in printf format it will be like this

```
partA(double num) {
    const int const max = 10000;
    const int const precision = 4;
    int width = 1 + log((float)max) / log(10.0f);
    for(; x <= max; x *= 10, num *= 10) {
        printf("%*d%c%.*f\n", width, x, 040, precision, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation of your output is wrong! You sure are quick to down vote others on a mistake... but as I can see, you do make mistakes also. Anyway, a good approach nonetheless.

Comment: Left-justify in 2 col fixed. I never said that I do not make mistakes‽

Comment: And that's why you have my +1

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for printf format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx).

To change the number of digits after the decimal point, specify the *precision*.

To get a space between the numbers, use a literal space in the format string, as in

```
printf("%d %4lf\n",x, num);
```